# Hide all select elements within a div using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How would I hide all of the 'select' html elements within a specific div using jquery?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the div has class "yourClass", then you can use:

```
$('div.yourClass').find('select').hide();
```

If you identify the div by id, then it is better to use only id in the selector:

```
$('#divId').find('select').hide();
```

You can also save one function call by using "[ancestor descendant](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/descendant#ancestordescendant)" selector:

```
$('#divId select').hide();
```